# Installing required drivers for a laptop before the windows boot up?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers, dvd

My Laptop HDD was broken (with factory settings partition). So, I replaced it with a new HDD which has nothing stored in it. I installed Windows 7 on it using an ISO burned to a DVD media.

Now I do not have required drivers. So, I have no internet, USB connectivity and DVD media too. I simply don't have any ways to get the driver files into the laptop.

Without asking for a replacement CD, is it possible or common to install drivers from a bootable disc before windows starts?

Devices detected with drivers not installed: 
Standard VDA Graphics adapter(probably nvidia card),
Ethernet Controller,
Network Controller,
PCI Simple communications Controller,
SM Bus controller,
Universal Serial Bus (USB) controller,
Unknown device.

I Have tried cabled connection, doesnt work- automatic diagnosis says no network driver is installed. DVD's are detected but no data is seen and windows thinks the discs are blank.

I downloaded the .iso from digital river, a licenced distibutor. Maybe it's just too basic and doesn't come with drivers.

Comment: Windows installs default drivers for many common devices, including HD, DVD, mouse, keyboard, network, etc. If you say you've reinstalled Windows, what exactly are you missing?

Comment: Have you tried detecting the hardware? Is connecting to the net with a wire an option? The wired interface should be configured by default.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question. If the wired connection should be working, well, it's not. Maybe I should try another copy of windows.

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases (no access to devices, but bootable from optical drive) I successfully used [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) live Linux CD to access the disk to copy files to it.

In fact, most [Live Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs) CDs can achieve this, they usually also provide internet access too, so you could even download the drivers to install to the HDD of the notebook. I think should give it a try.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but I have doubts about my ability to install drivers manually onto a device while outside of it.

Comment: @James you don't **install** the drivers. Just __copy them onto the HDD__. And then boot into Windows, and run the installers by starting them. The installers will be on the HDD, which must be available, as else you couldn't even boot up Windows...